# using pytorch for Gradient Descent

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

> my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class MultivariateLinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(3,1)

  def forward(self,x):
# print(1)
    return self.linear(x)


x_train = torch.FloatTensor([[73,80,75],
                             [93,88,93],
                             [89,91,90],
                             [96,98,100],
                             [73,66,70]])
y_train = torch.FloatTensor([[152],[185],[180],[196], [142]])

model = MultivariateLinearRegressionModel()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-5)
# print(222)
ep = 2000
for epoch in range(ep+1):
   hypothesis = model(x_train)

   cost = F.mse_loss(hypothesis, y_train)
   if epoch % 100 == 0:
     print('Epoch {:4d}/{} Cost: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch, 2000, cost.item()
    ))
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   cost.backward()
   optimizer.step()
```

> my problem:

this code is my own MultivariateLinearRegressionModel.

But in the for loop
`hypothesis = model(x_train)`  why this code is same with
`hypothesis = model.forward(x_train)` ??

i don't know why this 2 code statement is same.
is this a python grammar??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your model `MultivariateLinearRegressionModel` is inherited from `nn.Module` so when ever you call `model(x_train)`, it will automatically execute the `forward` function which is defined in `MultivariateLinearRegressionModel` class.

That's why `model(x_train)` and `model.forward(x_train)` give the same result.